# Cannot switch between classes every 1 second

Tags: jquery, html, class, timer, switch-statement

I am trying to switch my div class using a timer, and I'm always switching between 2 classes.

Here is the beginning of the div code

```html
<div id="this" class="photobanner">
```

You can check the JQuery function and timer I made below

```html
function autoAddClass(){
    if( $( '#this' ).hasClass( 'first' ))
        $('.first').addClass('last');
    if{$('#this').hasClass('last'))
        $('.last').addClass('first');
    }
 setTimeout(autoAddClass, 1000);
```

This is not working

Comment: If your code is called first, you have only class photobanner not class  first and not class last. So both if statements return false.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/szgzgfse/1/

Comment: Thanks, I have used photobanner instead of first in the div, now it works thanks to you and @soosmca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually second if statement you wrongly put '{' instead of '('. For verey second you have to change the class means Use setInterval

Your function be using toggleClass in jquery

```
function autoAddClass(){
    $('#this').toggleClass("first last");
}
$('#this').addClass('first');
setInterval(autoAddClass, 1000);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/szgzgfse/3/)

Comment: That almost works, but I still have one small problem:
I'm using two animations, last & first, first makes the pictures in the gallery scroll to the right, and first makes them scroll to the left, the problem is that when the class is switched to last, the pictures are not moving, they're just frozen (I have tested both classes before using timers and they both work fine)

Comment: I would guess you're animation takes longer than 1000 milli seconds.

Comment: I apologize, it's working now, i had a missing bracket somewhere, thanks!

Comment: @SeifHassine - Glad it helps

Answer (score 1):

```html
function autoAddClass(){
    if( $( '#this' ).hasClass( 'first' ))
        $('.first').addClass('last');
    if{$('#this').hasClass('last'))
        $('.last').addClass('first');
    }
 setTimeout(autoAddClass, 1000);
```

Your second if-clause is invalid. Try:
`if ($('#this').hasClass('last')) {...}`

Also, I think you should be using toggleClass, because after the first autoAddClass, your element will have both classes.

Comment: The last bracket } refers to the autoAddclass function, not the if statement
 -> EDIT: You are right, oups

Comment: @SeifHassine your if-clause start like `if{...`, that doesn't work

Comment: Yes you are right, but I don't know why the code is still not working

Answer (score 1):

Adding new classes to the elements is fine, but shouldn't you remove the existing class before adding a new one.

**JS CODE:**

```
setInterval(function(){
autoAddClass();}
, 1000);
     function autoAddClass() {
    console.log('timer elapsed');
    if ($('#container').hasClass('green')) {
        $('.green').removeClass('green').addClass('red');
    console.log('green');
    } else {
        $('.red').removeClass('red').addClass('green');
     console.log('red');
    }
}
```

**Live demo @ JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/mpLq6f7b/2/**

*Note:Never use `this` keyword for variables/id/class selectors, its a bad practice also  `this` is reserved keyword in `javascript`*

Comment: I edited (pending review) your code to fix a `{` that was in a wrong position from OP code (on the second if). Now your code should work has OP requested